# Inventory Available Quantity in Excel

Tags: excel, countif, inventory

I am creating an inventory list on Excel where I manually track what items get taken out on one sheet and I want it to automatically take this out of the available quantity on another sheet. So on sheet 1 there is a master inventory list where I manually add how much product I recieve. I named it "Quantity In".

[image]

On the second sheet is an inventory out tracker where I manually track what product I gave away

[image]

I want SHEET 1 to automatically take out from the "Quantity In" based on what item and the quantity taken out on SHEET 2.

What I Have Tried:
I have tried COUNTIF on SHEET 1 "QUANTITY OUT" based on how many times the item code is used in SHEET 2. And then subtracted "QUANTITY IN" and "QUANTITY OUT" to get "INVENTORY AVAILABLE". The problem is if more than one of item code on SHEET 2 is recorded: For example if I use "item code 4", it will record the amount of times I record "4" but not how many I record under "QUANTITY OUT" on SHEET 2. So if I give away 5 "item code 4" or "ruler" on a certain day, it only takes away 1 ruler because I only used item code 4 once.

Is there a way to track the SHEET 2 "QUANTITY IN" amount and have it automatically take away that amount from SHEET 1 "QUANTITY IN" to create an "INVENTORY AVAILABLE" value on SHEET ONE?

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is `SUMPRODUCT`. There are many good references on how to use on the interwebz, but [here is a site](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) that does exactly what you want.

So in column F, starting in Cell F2, use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$15=Sheet1!B2),Sheet2!$D$2:$D$15)
```

Comment: I tried this and I am still having the same problem where it won't count SHEET 2 "QUANTITY OUT" and only counts how many times "key" is mentioned on SHEET 2.